# Json Authentication from external website Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, authentication

I current have a Codeigniter 3 framework website (called external system), and I just purchased a helpdesk php script that include 2 files Json Authentication that help connect with external system.

My purpose is when users go to helpdesk and login, they need to use my current website login information, so they dont have to sign up again (in this way, the user information of helpdesk and my Codeigniter script can keep the same).

Backend of helpdesk has some fields that need to provide like: url, site id, authentication key, create users on login.

Helpdesk script has 2 files and they need to be uploaded to external system, index.php and Authclass.php. Authclass.php is just class and function for encryption(no need to customize this). So i think Authclass.php will need to upload to library folder in Application of Codeigniter. The code of index.php is below.

Can anyone please help me or suggest where upload these files to codeigniter folder and how to modify to make it work?

Thank you so much

**index.php**

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

include('authclass.php');
$auth = new auth();

$send_array['success'] = 0;

if (isset($_POST['site_id']) && isset($_POST['data'])) {
   if ($_POST['site_id'] == 1) {

    /*Set your authentication key here*/

    $auth->set('key', '');

    $data = $auth->decrypt($_POST['data']);
    $receive_array = json_decode($data, true);
    if (is_array($receive_array)) {
        if ($receive_array['task'] == 'authenticate') {

            /*This would connect to your external database here.*/

            if ($receive_array['username'] == 'username' && $receive_array['password'] == 'password') {
                $send_array['success']  = 1;
                $send_array['name']     = 'example name';
                $send_array['email']    = 'example@example.com';                
            }
            echo $auth->encrypt(json_encode($send_array));  
        }
    }
}
}

?>
```

**authclass.php**

```
class auth {

  private $config = array();
  private $user = array();

  function __construct() {  
    $this->config['key']                = '';
  }

  public function set($name, $value) {
    $this->config[$name] = $value;
  }
  ....
```

**Update on what i have tried index.php (in controller folder) below is renamed to helpdesk.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');


    public function helpdesk() { 
        $this->load->library('auth');

        $this -> new auth();
        $send_array['success'] = 0;

        if (isset($_POST['site_id']) && isset($_POST['data'])) {
            if ($_POST['site_id'] == 1) {

    /*
        Set your authentication key here
    */
    $this->auth->set('key', 'test1234');

    $data = $this->auth->decrypt($_POST['data']);
    $receive_array = json_decode($data, true);
    if (is_array($receive_array)) {
        if ($receive_array['task'] == 'authenticate') {
            /*
                This is where your auth function exists (you would connect to your external database here).
            */
            if ($receive_array['username'] == ['email'] && $receive_array['password'] == ['password']) {
                $send_array['success']  = 1;
                $send_array['name']     = ['username'];
                $send_array['username']     = ['email'];    
                $send_array['password']     = ['password'];                 
            }
            echo $this->auth->encrypt(json_encode($send_array));    
        }
    }
}
}
}


?>
```

**authclass.php was remaned to auth.php and uploaded to library folder, i have tried to modified**

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class auth {

  protected $ci; //in case you need to call CI's functions

  function __construct($params = array()) 
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->ci = get_instance();

  }

  private $config = array();
  private $user = array();

  function __construct() {  
    $this->config['key']                = '';
  }

  public function set($name, $value) {
    $this->config[$name] = $value;
  }
  ............
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note: depending on what authclass.php looks like this may or may not work.)

Rename authclass.php to Auth.php (case sensitive), make sure the classname at the top of that file is "Auth", and put it in application/libraries.

Create a controller with following function:

```
function test(){
   $this->load->library('auth');
   $auth = new auth();
   /* rest of index.php code should work */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it still does not work. I have updated on what i have tried. And Auth.php is just function to encrypt the data using base64 and rindale. Thanks again

Comment: It's a long shot but I noticed the library class and the controller carry the same name (Auth). Try giving the controller a different name (and corresponding filename).

Comment: In any case, seeing the library auth class code would help.

Comment: I checked and fixed as Adrien said, but it did not work, so i just update part of authclass coding in library because i am worry it might violate when sharing coding of other authors. Again thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi again, I have updated on what i have tried, please help me take a look. Thank you so much and im really appreciated

Comment: Remove `$this -> new auth();` from your code (controller). Also: the auth class file should be named Auth.php, and the class name in it should be `class Auth`.

Comment: I Found some errors in server log from auth.log... sshd[29491]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ip.... user=root sshd[29491]: Failed password for root from ip.... port 60354 ssh2
sshd[29491]: Received disconnect from ip...11: Bye Bye [preauth]
 sshd[29500]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ip.... user=root
 sshd[29500]: Failed password for root from ip... port 55187 ssh2
 sshd[29500]: Accepted password for root from ip... port 55187 ssh2
 sshd[29500]: pam_unix(sshd:session)

Comment: I also get error from helpdesk: Unknown user. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You are right about converting their authclass into a library. Make sure the function you will need to call are public.

So in `application/libraries`

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class HelpdeskAuth
{
    protected $ci; //in case you need to call CI's functions

    function __construct($params = array()) 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->ci = get_instance();

    }

    //Their code here
}
```

And for their `index.php`. you can create a new controller and paste the code inside the `index()` function or write a new function in an existing controller.

You just need to make sure that your are correctly calling the library we created

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library("HelpdeskAuth");

    $send_array['success'] = 0;

    if (isset($_POST['site_id']) && isset($_POST['data'])) 
    {
       if ($_POST['site_id'] == 1) 
       {

            /*Set your authentication key here*/

            $this->HelpdeskAuth->set('key', '');

            $data = $this->HelpdeskAuth->decrypt($_POST['data']);
            $receive_array = json_decode($data, true);
            if (is_array($receive_array)) 
            {
                if ($receive_array['task'] == 'authenticate') 
                {
                    /*This would connect to your external database here.*/

                    if ($receive_array['username'] == 'username' && $receive_array['password'] == 'password') {
                        $send_array['success']  = 1;
                        $send_array['name']     = 'example name';
                        $send_array['email']    = 'example@example.com';                
                    }
                    echo $this->HelpdeskAuth->encrypt(json_encode($send_array));  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also convert all the `$_POST['']` to `$this->input->post('')` and use `$this->output->set_output()` instead of the final echo, but it is not mandatory

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just did exactly as you mentioned but it did not work. I checked everything. Do you think receive_array and send_array was set wrong as i set above? And i just update part of authclass code in library because i am worry it might violate when sharing coding of other author. Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't have ` $auth = new auth();` anymore, it's what `$this->load->library()` does. You should use `$this->auth instead()` of `$auth`. Do you have any error besides that ?

Comment: This i removed it and used $this->auth. Thank you again

Comment: Hi again, I have updated on what i have tried, please help me take a look. Thank you so much and im really appreciated

Comment: Hi Adrien, there is no error message. After i coded as above and uploaded to my codeigniter website. I went to helpdesk website and try to use the information of users of my codeigniter website to login. It just said login failed. Is there anyway i could check if my website actually pass information to helpdesk login form. Thank you again

Comment: Create some logs messages : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html?#log_message

Comment: Hi, i Found some errors in server log from auth.log... sshd[29491]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ip....  user=root sshd[29491]: Failed password for root from ip.... port 60354 ssh2
sshd[29491]: Received disconnect from ip... 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
 sshd[29500]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ip....  user=root
 sshd[29500]: Failed password for root from ip... port 55187 ssh2
 sshd[29500]: Accepted password for root from ip... port 55187 ssh2
 sshd[29500]: pam_unix(sshd:session)..

Comment: I also get error from helpdesk: Unknown user. Thank you again